# CodeIgniter not reacting to post

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

When I submit a form for the url `example.com/index.php/topic/1/test-topic-test` CodeIgniter does not recognize that a post form is submitted.

Routes:

```
$route["topic/(:num)/([a-z]+)"]["post"] = "forums/topic_post_reply/$1/$2";
```

Forums.php controller:

```
    public function topic_post_reply($id, $name)
    {
        $message = $this->input->post("topic_reply_content");
        if(!empty($message) && !empty($this->session->userdata('id')))
        {
            $data = [
                "content" => $message,
                "author" => $this->session->userdata('id'),
                "reply_date" => time(),
                "parent" => $id
            ];

            $this->db->insert("forum_topics_replies", $data);
        }
        else
        {
            die("Something went wrong");
        }
    }
```

Form:

```
<form class="uk-form-stacked" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/topic/<?php echo $this->uri->segment(2); ?>/<?php echo $this->forums_model->slug($this->uri->segment(3)); ?>" method="post">
<div class="uk-form-inline">
    <textarea class="uk-textarea" name="topic_reply_content" rows="4" placeholder="Write a lovely reply..."></textarea>
</div>

<div class="laevis-reply-hidden">
    <div class="uk-margin-small" style="margin-bottom:0">
        <input type="submit" class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-width-1-1" value="Post">
    </div>
</div>
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Instead of `<?php echo $this->uri->segment(2); ?>` you have to pass known variable to action URL.

Comment: @Tpojka Thanks, but this did not fix the problem.

Comment: Can you insert hard coded data without if condition and without form? Just for testing purposes.

Comment: @Tpojka `topic_post_reply()` is not being called at all, nothing in the function works. And yes I can insert hard coded data to that table.

Comment: Have you tried with hard coded values in form action URL? Also, enable error logging. Check if there are server errors or php errors in `/var/log/apache2/` directory for example if Ubuntu with Apache is used.

Comment: @Tpojka There are no errors in any logs. And hard coded routing does not work either.

Comment: When debugging you need to be able to reproduce the problem with the minimum code required. You've asked a question about routing, but also have session usage, database usage, etc. There's certainly no way we can test your code. Do you see what I'm saying? If your question is about routing, then give us a route and a URL and we can check it. Have you tried that?

Comment: I managed to find the solution. I answered my own question, see it below.

Comment: Try without verb in route to get there when you can distinct working against not working. Debug everything you can think about.

Comment: Okay, thanks for all the input!

Comment: Glad you solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to have the post route above all other routes for the same url or it would not work. I also had to change it to `$route["topic/(:num)/:any"]["post"]`.